# How to use FileSavePicker.PickSaveFileAndContinue in Prism app?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, prism

I am writing universal app using Prism framework and I don't understand how to use FileSavePicker.PickSaveFileAndContinue in WP project. The most unclear part is app activation.
According to Richter's post in Wintellect blog, in usual app it should be something like:

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args) 
{
args.OnActivatedForContinuation(((Frame)Window.Current.Content).Content);
base.OnActivated(args);
}
```

But in Prism app I don't use stuff like Frame class directly.

Comment: Hi @Hozuki Ferrari, I'm not sure what you mean. Every ViewModel has an OnNavigatedTo override that is hit whenever you navigate to e new View. You can start from there I guess?

Answer (score 0):

OnActivateForContinuation is an extension method that Richter describes in his book.
His post explains that there is source code available for the extension methods Available from the Wintellect website, at http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/category/resources.